# Geometric interpretation of projection of 3D point w/ camera matrix

Tags: coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, computer-vision

The subject is Pinhole Camera.

I've given a camera matrix $P =  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$ and a 3D point $X_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1  \\
   -1 \\
    1
    \end{pmatrix}$

After computing the projection of the 3D point (w/ homo coordinates) $X_3$ in the camera w/ the camera matrix, by $PX_3$, I got to $A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1  \\
   0 
    \end{pmatrix}$ .

I'm asked to describe the geometric interpretation of $A$.

The point here contains $Z = 0$ which I'm trying to figure out its geometric interpretation. AFAIK, it should be a point in infinity or something like that. Any help is appreciated.

From wikipedia:

[image]

Comment: That’s exactly right: the image of $X_3$ is a point at infinity. Now think about this in terms of the image plane in the scene: which rays through the camera center intersect it on its line at infinity? What does that say about the position of $X_3$ relative to the camera’s stance?